# Bulk renaming of files by extracting characters between the first and second underscore in the filename

Tags: sed, rename

I'm trying to bulk rename files in a folder with sed, rename or any other way in OSX. I'd like to retain a part of the file name that's between the first and second underscore. For example rename "JAS_9877_FF_0023.jpg" to "9877.jpg" and I need to do this for hundreds of files.

Thanks,

Z.

Comment: Do you have *any* preference about tools? `rename "s/[^_]*_\([0-9]*\).*\.jpg/\1.jpg/" *` might do it, but I don't have `rename` handy, so I can't test it. I can give solutions in Make, bash and/or Perl, if those would help.

Comment: I'd upvote a solution in `make`! I've never seen that!

Comment: @Beta, I don't have any preference about tools. I tried your rename suggestion but get the following error in return: \1 better written as $1 at (eval 2) line 1.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I got it working with:

for a in * ; do mv $a $(echo $a | cut -d'_' -f 2).jpg ; done